# Localized app name does appear in English only via App Store app on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-appstore, internationalization

I have a weird issues. There is my app which I localized for multiple languages following Apple guidelines. All works well, app reacts to the language on the phone, I can see localized app name by using App Store via VPN to some country, etc.

However, when I switch phone to German, for example, switch App Store app to Germany, and then search my app via its German name, app store finds it, but **displays its name in German**.

I am not sure why this is happening only via App Store app on the iphone itself.

Did anyone have such problems and how did you solve them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues has been resoled by contacting Apple and they did something internally. 
Over the night, we started getting proper results.

So if you have such issues, do not break your head, but contact Apple.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you need to do localization in the "General > App Information" tab in App Store Connect, as well as the `CFBundle` stuff in Info.plist.

Answer (score 0):

This is intentional behaviour.

From [this Apple page:](https://developer.apple.com/internationalization/)

> Localize your app name and update your App Store metadata, such as your app description, keywords, and screenshots, for each of the countries in which you offer your app.

It has probably been updated automatically.

Comment: I do not understand your answer. What do you mean "it's intentional behaviour"? Shouldn't the name appear in the localized language like German?